# IIS 7 using an SSL cert for default sites that do not have https bound or certs assigned

Tags: iis, ssl, https

I have a IIS7 server with several sites on it lets call them 'Site A','Site B','Site C','Site D' and 'Site E'.  Site A to C are basic sites and share a common IP (this is the default server IP), Sites D and E host more complex sites and each have a unique IPs and SSL certs assigned (these IP's are from a different block).

When for some reason a user trys to connect to sites A to C with https:// they get an SSL error and are shown 'Site D's' certificate name.

I cannot see how this is being assigned, and I would have thought the separate IPs would not have allowed this to occur. The cert assigned is alphabetically superior and was also created first. So that might be the reason why?

I can't understand why a cert that is not specifically assign to an IP is being used - especially for site that aren't eve using port 443 and after searching around have not been able to find this discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that your server's initially setup does not match your description right now, which leads to inconsistent certificate mapping resides in http.sys settings.

You can run `netsh http show sslcert` to print out all existing mappings and revise them accordingly.

For example, sites bind to certain IPs should have their certificates map to those IP addresses only, instead of `0.0.0.0` which interferes with other sites.